# Postgres for Airflow backend DB to create metadata tables in a specified schema

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, airflow, psycopg2

I'm setting up postgres backend for Airflow metadata DB using the following sqlalchemy connection string:

```
sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://<user>:<pass>@<host>:5432/<db>
```

When I run initdb/upgradedb, the tables are created in public schema.

Is there a way to create the tables in a specified schema?

Can the schema where I would like the tables to be created be specified as part of the connection string?

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/initialize-database.html):

> Also note that since SqlAlchemy does not expose a way to target a specific schema in the Postgres connection URI, you may want to set a default schema for your role with a command similar to ALTER ROLE username SET search_path = airflow, foobar;

So, connect to postgres, and set the search path for your user.