# How to specify a postgres schema (and search_path) in airflow an official airflow helm chart deployment

Tags: postgresql, airflow, azure-aks

I am trying to use the official airflow helm chart to deploy the airflow version 2.8 on Azure Kubernetes cluster. I intend to use postgres as the metadata database. I am aware that I can specify the connection in the below section of the values.yaml file. However, it is creating the metadata tables in the public schema. I would want to be able to use a specific schema (Ex. airflow_meta or airflow_config).

How can I achieve this?
Do I need to make any modifications to search_path on the postgres side? Should I need to make any changes in the helm chart for search path?

metadataConnection:
user: postgres
pass: postgres
protocol: postgresql
host: ~
port: 5432
db: postgres
sslmode: disable

Looked all the configuration in helm chart - values.yaml but could not any variable/configuration for search path

Comment: Refer to this- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65277470/postgres-for-airflow-backend-db-to-create-metadata-tables-in-a-specified-schema

Comment: Before deploying Airflow, connect to your Postgres database and create the desired schema.  In the same Postgres session, set the search_path for the user that Airflow will use to connect to the database. Finally deploy Airflow from helm, specifying the connection details in the values.yaml file. After Airflow is deployed, it will run database migrations using the user provided details. Since you've set the search_path to your custom schema, the tables will be created in airflow_meta. After deployment, you can verify that the tables have indeed been created in the airflow_meta schema.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion .. Even in airflow2.8 we need follow set default schema at Database/user level. 

Can we pass from dynamically using helm chart configuration?

Comment: I guess in the official Airflow Helm chart wrt to its usage with PostgreSQL, the search_path setting (which determines the default PostgreSQL schema) is not something that can be set directly through the Helm chart values.

Answer (score 0):

To specify a Postgres schema (and search_path) for Airflow when deploying using Helm chart, you will indeed need to adjust the `search_path` on the Postgres side. The Helm chart itself does not provide a direct way to specify the schema/search path because it's not a standard Airflow configuration parameter.

Here’s how you can achieve using a specific schema:
*[Create the Schema in Postgres](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/postgresql-create-schema/)*: Before deploying Airflow, connect to your Postgres database and create the desired schema:

```
CREATE SCHEMA airflow_meta;
```

*[Set the Search Path](https://www.commandprompt.com/education/postgresql-schema-search-path/)*: In the same Postgres session, set the `search_path` for the user that Airflow will use to connect to the database:

```
ALTER USER airflow_user SET search_path TO airflow_meta;
```

Replace `airflow_user` with the actual username that Airflow will use.

*[Deploy Airflow with Helm](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/index.html)*: Use the Helm chart to deploy Airflow, specifying the connection details in the `values.yaml` file:

```yaml
metadataConnection:
  user: airflow_user
  pass: airflow_pass
  protocol: postgresql
  host: my_postgres_host
  port: 5432
  db: my_airflow_db
  sslmode: disable
```

1. Ensure that `my_airflow_db` is the database where you've set the `search_path`.
2. Run Database Migrations: After Airflow is deployed, it will run database migrations using the user provided. Since you've set the `search_path` to your custom schema, the tables will be created in `airflow_meta`.
3. Post-Deployment Check: After deployment, you may want to connect to your Postgres database and verify that the tables have indeed been created in the `airflow_meta` schema.

By the way, if you're using a managed Postgres service in Azure (like Azure Database for PostgreSQL), you can use the service's query editor or connect using `psql` or another database tool to run these commands.

Remember, whenever you connect to the database using the `airflow_user`, the default schema will be `airflow_meta` because of the `search_path` setting. All Airflow tables should thus be created and accessed in that schema.

As of Airflow 2.8 and the current capabilities of the Helm chart, you cannot directly configure the PostgreSQL `search_path` at the database/user level through the Airflow Helm chart's `values.yaml` file. The Helm chart primarily configures Airflow application settings, and the `search_path` is inherently a database-level setting specific to PostgreSQL.

Reference-

[Similar SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65277470/postgres-for-airflow-backend-db-to-create-metadata-tables-in-a-specified-schema)

[Setting up a PostgreSQL Database](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/set-up-database.html)

[Airflow guide](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/production-guide.html)